# Cannot use SSH via internal IP address but can ping it easily

Tags: ssh, ping, cloud, oracle

I have this setup in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure ...

I have two networks ..

**Network 1**:

```
internal cidr: 192.168.1.0/24
public IP: 10.0.0.1
```

**Network 2**:

```
internal cidr: 192.168.2.0/24
public IP: 10.0.0.2
```

connected via OCI tool -> "Local Peering Gateway" (without this, I couldn't even ping) ...

both are running SSHD and are accessible/connectable via SSH by their PUBLIC IP addresses ..

This all works fine ...

However, when I want to connect from the Network 1 to Network two via internal IP address, I cannot ... even tho it pings fine

```
admin@network1:$ ping 192.168.2.10
PING 192.168.2.10 (192.168.2.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=154 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=152 ms
```

from tho other network, I cannot ping tho

```
admin@network2:$ ping 192.168.1.10
PING 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 155.0.10.38 ping statistics ---
347 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 354309ms
```

The traceroute shows a lot of asterisks on the way .. and nmap from both machines does not show any open ports ... which is weird because publicly they are opened and I cannot via the public IP using ssh without a problem...

Any idea what could it be? I am kinda helpless .... especially because of OCI does not really provide support on this matter and many services do not provide logs :(

PS: Pls do not advice to change the provider/cloud .. I cannot - that's clients request ..

----------- EDIT:

wireshark ping log

```
admin@network1$ sudo tshark -i ens3 | grep 192.168.2.10
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on 'ens3'
281   273 13.491209915  192.168.1.10 → 192.168.2.10 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000f, seq=1/256, ttl=64
300   279 13.644608152 192.168.2.10 → 192.168.1.10  ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000f, seq=1/256, ttl=54 (request in 273)
313   295 14.492540119  192.168.1.10 → 192.168.2.10 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x000f, seq=2/512, ttl=64
298 14.645324623 192.168.2.10 → 192.168.1.10  ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x000f, seq=2/512, ttl=54 (request in 295)
```

wireshark for ssh connection:

```
643   628 37.001410195  192.168.1.10 → 192.168.2.10 TCP 74 [TCP Retransmission] 36306 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1327517210 TSecr=0 WS=128
855   854 53.226989006  192.168.1.10 → 192.168.2.10 TCP 74 45260 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1327533435 TSecr=0 WS=128
945   912 54.281406442  192.168.1.10 → 192.168.2.10 TCP 74 [TCP Retransmission] 45260 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1327534490 TSecr=0 WS=128
963   948 56.329410437  192.168.1.10 → 192.168.2.10 TCP 74 [TCP Retransmission] 45260 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1327536538 TSecr=0 WS=128
1004   991 60.361413567  192.168.1.10 → 192.168.2.10 TCP 74 [TCP Retransmission] 45260 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1327540570 TSecr=0 WS=128
```

Comment: None of the address you mention are *public* IP addresses.  They're in [RFC-1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) private addresses (i.e. 192.168/16, 172.16/12, and 10/8).   Are they the actual addresses you're using or did you anonymise them?

Comment: I did use these dummy addresses ofc :)

Comment: that's an ambiguous answer, it could be interpreted either way.  are they the actual ip addresses you used, or did you anonymise them for your question?

Comment: thes eare not real addresses ofc... I cannot disclose the topography.. anyway.. as per the wireshark, it's clear the other server does not respond to SYN with SYN+ACK .... I need to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the two networks are connected. Or if they are, you've not got routes on the two servers configured via the router.

Furthermore, I think the ping is irrelevant other than there's a machine somewhere with the target address that's responding - it's not necessarily your machine.

You can look at the routing tables on the two servers to confirm they know about the "other" network.

You can install Wireshark (the command line implementation is called `tshark`) and use that to verify a ping is being received and/or a response is being sent

Comment: could you check the edit pls? thank you @roaiama

Comment: `tcpdump` is another good command-line option.  and it should be run on both ends simultaneously (or at least on the host which is the target of the ping request) so you can see if that host is actually receiving the pings (i.e. that they're not being intercepted by something in between the two machines).  e.g. something like `tcpdump -l -n -i <iface> icmp and net 192.168.1.0/23` (where <iface> is the name of the interface - e.g. eth0, br0, whatever).

Comment: well ok .. .so it seems the ping is not really working fine... for I run ping form the N1 -> N2 machine.. and it again seemed to be reaching...

but I run the TCPDUMP and TSHARK on the N2 machine .. and nothing from the N1 machine's IP was popping up... so yeah, the network ain't ok... 

I am gonna get back to routing tables, sec lists and LPG setup